# Filter a form using a command button on another form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a form with a cmdbutton that at the moment opens another form and shows all records for several types of PartitionStyles and TrimFinishs (486 at present), I need to be able to filter the second form to show only the TrimFinish I need.

Private Sub lbl600SeriesS_Click()
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

```
stDocName = "frmModules"
stLinkCriteria = "Forms!frmModules![TrimFinish] = 1"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
```

End Sub

At the moment it shows only a new record, I know there should be 162 records using 1, what have I missed or done incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base stLinkCriteria on a field in frmModules' RecordSource.  So, if the RecordSource includes a numeric field named TrimFinish, try something like this:

```
stLinkCriteria = "[TrimFinish] = 1"
```

If the RecordSource is a query drawing from more than one table, you can qualify the field name with the table alias:

```
stLinkCriteria = "YourTableAlias.[TrimFinish] = 1"
```

If you still have trouble, edit your question to describe frmModules' RecordSource.  If it's a query, paste in the SQL View of the query.

Comment: Thanks, stLinkCriteria = "[TrimFinish] = 1" works.
I have been asked if I can add another filter for PartitionStyle within the same section of code.

Comment: @Shaun Filter for PartitionStyle instead of, or in addition to, filter for TrimFinish?  Is PartitionStyle text or numeric data type?

Comment: HansUp.

Managed to sort it.

Private Sub lbl600SeriesS_Click()
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
    
    stDocName = "frmModules"
    stLinkCriteria = "[PartitionStyle] = 1"
    stLinkCriteria = stLinkCriteria & "AND [TrimFinish] = 1"
    
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
       
End Sub

Cheers.